# Multiple Images Selection From Custom Activity not from gallery

Tags: android, android-image

I have fetch few selected Images from external storage and now I have to give option to choose multiple images same as like Gallery from that images. Please note I don't want to open gallery for multiple image selection. Its process in custom activity. I have tried few GitHub libraries but all having option to select images from gallery. Suggest any library code for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

[Fragment from my store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iunvf.png)
[Fragment from my store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49xUI.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49xUI.png)

1. Create a list of objects
2. Add flag on image object. For example:

   Public class imageObject{
   Private String fileName;
   Private boolean isChecked;
   Public imageObject(String fileName){
   IsChecked = false;
   this.filename= fileName;
   }
   }
3. Create adapter for recyclerview and
   Add onClick on viewHolder from adapter:

   Boolean state=imageList.get(getAdapterPosition()).isChecked();
   ImageList.get(getAdapterPisition()).setChecked(!state);
   notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition

It depends on where list located, in activity/fragment or inside of adapter. If in act/frag make interface to interract between adapter and act/frag.

4. Add in onBindViewHolder() code:

   If (list.get(position).isChecked()){
   //just show that item checked
   }
   else{
   // just show that item doesn't checked))
   }
5. After that you can freely find checked items by iterations, like:

   private deleteItems(){
   for(int i=0; i< imageList.size(); i++){
   if(imageList.get(i).isChecked())
   imageList.remove(i);
   }
   imagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

Oh well, so difficult to write from phone))

Comment: I have applied same code as you described but not functionality as much good as gallery multiple selection process. For this code I have to work too much in code

Comment: Obviosly I'll not give you the full code, but I used this logic in my store, you could see screenshorts on my answer